# Find out the maximum number of decimal places within a string of numbers

Tags: javascript, string, function, char, string-search

The string looks like this like something along the lines of `3*2.2`or `6+3.1*3.21` or `(1+2)*3,1+(1.22+3)` or `0.1+1+2.2423+2.1` it can vary a bit. I have to find the amount of decimal places in the number inside the `string` with the most decimal places.

Im totally helpless on how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find all numbers that have decimal places and then use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find the highest amount of decimal places.

```js
const input = '0.1+1+2.2423+2.1';

const maxNumberOfDecimalPlaces = input
  .match(/((?<=\.)\d+)/g)
  ?.reduce((acc, el) =>
    acc >= el.length ?
    acc :
    el.length, 0) ?? 0;

console.log(maxNumberOfDecimalPlaces);
```

Note that this will return `0` when no numbers with decimal places are found in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You may do the following:

- [`Array.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your input string by RegExp [`/\[^\d.\]+/`](https://regex101.com/r/8Le6BL/1) to extract numbers
- traverse resulting array of numbers with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and split those by decimal separator into `whole` and `fractional` parts, returning the `length` of the fractional part or 0 (for integers)
- use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to find the maximum `length`

Above method seems to be more robust as it does not involve certain not well supported features:

- RegExp lookbehinds assertions (`/(?<=)/`) which [may not be supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility) by certain popular browsers like Safari or Firefox (below current version)
- latest features, like [conditional chaining (`.?`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility) or [nulish coalescing (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Browser_compatibility)

```js
const src = ['3*2.2', '6+3.1*3.21', '(1+2)*3' , '1+(1.22+3)', '0.1+1+2.2423+2.1'],

      maxDecimals = s => 
       Math.max(
        ...s
          .split(/[^\d.]+/)
          .map(n => {
            const [whole, fract] = n.split('.')
            return fract ? fract.length : 0
          })
       )
      
        
src.forEach(s => console.log(`Input: ${s}, result: ${maxDecimals(s)}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: yes works perfectly thanks =) now im off to understanding it :)

Comment: @Sofia : I have re-factored my answer to be more robust as it  had  certain compatibility issues, ***just like the answer you currently marked accepted have***

Comment: my problem was simply that it was not easily understandable for me, i needed the decimal number as a variable to work with and couldnt figure it out quickly how to do

Comment: @Sofia : in my current solution there's a `fract` variable that holds fractional part of floats, and it uses very basic RegExp which is much easier to comprehend than lookbehind assertions, the rest of it are very basic `.split()` and `.map()`, so if it seems to you that in addition to being more robust (***since other two solutions may simply fail in some popular browsers***) my current solution is more comprehensive, feel free to re-accept.

Comment: okay i will try it out now... im about to ask another question about a problem with regex im having x]

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex pattern

```js
var str="6+3.1*3.21"
d=str.match(/(?<=\d)[.]\d{1,}/g)
d!=null ? res=d.map((n,i) => ({["number" + (i+1) ] : n.length - 1}))
: res = 0
console.log(res)
```